# Custom UITableViewCell Selection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I am finding a problem that I am unable to solve. At the moment I have a tableView with custom cells and in the custom cells I've written my own setHighlighted and setSelected method. The problem that I am facing is this: when a cell is highlighted then selected a 'staggering' animation is occurring from

- highlighted: true animated: false
- highlighted: false animated: false
- selected: true animated: false
- selected: true animated: true

What am I missing? How do I fix this?

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

    if highlighted == true {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.selectionView.backgroundColor = .red
        })
    } else if highlighted == false {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.selectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        })
    }
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected == true && animated == true {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.selectionView.backgroundColor = .red
        })

    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.selectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt I'm referring to the fact that this current usecase it's causing a bug. I'll edit it out if you prefer

Comment: @matt I'm sorry, I'm confused as to what you're saying the mistake in my code is? Can you elaborate on this please?